# Wordpress Ajax not function as I expect... what's wrong?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In functions.php I have:

```
function testajax() {
echo "test";
exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_testthisajax', 'testajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_testthisajax', 'testajax');
```

In scripts.js I have:

```
$("#thisformsid").submit( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: CustomAjax.ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action: 'testthisajax'
            },
            success: function(result){
                    console.log('success: ', result);
                },
                error: function(xhr){
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                },
                complete: function(result){
                    console.log('complete: ', result);
                }
        })
    });
```

My form is using the correct id and I can reach the ajax submit in my scripts.js file

The url is defined in scripts.js like:

```
var CustomAjax = {
    ajaxurl: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
};
```

However this fails. In console I see an error and the value "0" returned. ANy ideas why this would not work? It seems like this, as basic as it is, should not error out but I don't see the problem. Any ideas?

---

**Update:**
In console I see that the error is labeled as being on line 18 of my install of jquery (it's minified so i don't know what is actually at that line)? Why would there be an issue with jquery?

Answer (score 2):

First try to perform this without JS altogether. Just visit link `yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=testthisajax`.

`0` seems like something kinda works, but not quite. If I remember right failed requests should be `-1`.

Comment: This works as expected. Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: @gaoshan88 not sure... Are you using proper noConflict wrapper around your jQuery code?

Comment: Well, I tried with both $(...) and jQuery(...). Would that be insufficient?

Comment: There's `noConflict();` to be used _inside_ and _on top_ of the jQuery function. Then there's `function($) { etc.` so you can use `$` savely _inside_ the function. But the function always has to start with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enqueued `jquery-form`? Also look for dependencies. If you look at the 3rd parameter, then you'll see that you can set them. So there should be `jquery` enqueued and registered first, then `jquery-form` and then your custom stuff.

Comment: jquery form... I am not doing anything with that. Is it necessary? What role does it play?

Comment: No, it's not necessary. Only if you want to pass pre-post or past-post data alongside your post data - it's just an easy & nice way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your CustomAjax url using `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`

```
<?php print("var CustomAjax = '" . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) . "';\n");?>
```

Even better would be to pass the AjaxUrl using wp_localize_script:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui' ), false);
wp_localize_script( 'scripts', 'CustomAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it works fine - I get "success:test" on my domain.

But, I managed to get "0" - by changing ajax url from: 
mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 
to
www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Using ajax, you can make requests to the same domain only.
Is it so in your case?

Comment: [Further reading stuff for the with/out www](http://www.google.at/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=with+without+www+.htaccess).